# Difficulty importing text file with multiple different delimiters in R

Tags: r

I'm having trouble figuring out how to import my data with multiple delimiters. The following is what my computer automatically saves into text file. The issue is that some of the results are printed with differently spaced delimiters. Some of the delimiters are colons (:) and others are multiple spaces with inconsistent length.

Each letter (B: to Z:) codes for some unique variable. For example:

- B: Number of responses
- C: Number of seconds, etc.

However, the information below "Z: 0.000", where the layout changes, is when the variables get subset. So,

- A:
- 0: value1   value2   value3  value4

is referenced as:

- A(0) = value1 (e.x. number of responses in the first trial)
- A(1) = value2 (e.x. number of responses in the second trial)
- A(2) = value3 (e.x. number of responses in the third trial)
- A(3) = value4 (e.x. number of responses in the fourth trial)

Here, there are 4 "A" variables that each can carry unique values too.

Example of Text File:

```
Start Date: 05/20/18
End Date: 05/20/18
Subject: 1
Start Time: 16:23:11
End Time: 17:26:24
B:       7.000
C:   12000.000
D:    9500.000
E:       1.000
Q:     203.000
T:    1200.100
U:     218.000
W:       7.000
X:     347.000
Y:       0.000
Z:       0.000
A:
     0:        1.000        0.000        0.000        0.000
F:
     0:    11500.000     9500.000    13500.000     7500.000    15500.000
     5:     5500.000    17500.000
```

I've tried a few methods, but they get stuck because the multiple delimiters issue. Let's assume "data" is the text file.

```
# This is the closest - some of the values are still not separated properly

temp <- read.delim2(file = "data", quote = ":", sep = "",)

# This one separate the information mostly correctly for the top half only

temp <- read.delim2(file = "data", sep = ":")
```

I eventually want a dataframe with labels in one column (StartDate, A(0), B, etc.) and values in the other (05/20/2018, 1, 7).

Comment: Are the whitespace and linebreaks in your example actually in the text file you're trying to parse? It's a useful example that makes it easy to see the format, but could you also paste in a few lines of the raw text file that we can use to test methods of dealing with the data?

Comment: The example is the actual format that is found in my text file (so yes - the whitespace and linebreaks are shown exactly as they are in the file). It appears that the lower half of the file organizes it in columns aligned to the right per column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(splitstackshape)

#read file
txt <- readLines("test.txt")

#Fix 'A:' rows
A_idx <- grep("A:", txt)
txt[A_idx] <- paste0(txt[A_idx], gsub("0:\\s+", "", txt[A_idx+1]))
txt <- txt[-(A_idx+1)]

#Fix 'F:' rows
F_idx <- grep("F:", txt)
txt[F_idx] <- paste0(txt[F_idx], paste(gsub("0:\\s+", "", txt[F_idx+1]), 
                                       gsub("5:\\s+", "", txt[F_idx+2])))
txt <- txt[-c(F_idx+1, F_idx+2)]
```

Now `txt` is in DCF format so it can be read using `read.dcf`

```
df <- data.frame(read.dcf(textConnection(txt)), stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  cSplit("A", " ") %>%
  cSplit("F", " ")
```

**Output is:**

```
df

   Start.Date End.Date Subject Start.Time End.Time     B         C        D     E       Q        T
1:   05/20/18 05/20/18       1   16:23:11 17:26:24 7.000 12000.000 9500.000 1.000 203.000 1200.100
         U     W       X     Y     Z A_1 A_2 A_3 A_4   F_1  F_2   F_3  F_4   F_5  F_6   F_7
1: 218.000 7.000 347.000 0.000 0.000   1   0   0   0 11500 9500 13500 7500 15500 5500 17500
```

**Sample data:** `test.txt` contains

```
Start Date: 05/20/18
End Date: 05/20/18
Subject: 1
Start Time: 16:23:11
End Time: 17:26:24
B:       7.000
C:   12000.000
D:    9500.000
E:       1.000
Q:     203.000
T:    1200.100
U:     218.000
W:       7.000
X:     347.000
Y:       0.000
Z:       0.000
A:
  0:        1.000        0.000        0.000        0.000
F:
  0:    11500.000     9500.000    13500.000     7500.000    15500.000
  5:     5500.000    17500.000

Start Date: 05/20/18
End Date: 05/20/18
... another block of data
```

---

**Edit:** If you want column `A` & `F`'s index to start from 0

```
#read DCF data (i.e 'txt') using read.dcf
df <- data.frame(read.dcf(textConnection(txt)), stringsAsFactors = F)

#convert column A into wide format by splitting it into multiple columns
A_df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(df$A),'\\s+')), stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(A_df) <- paste("A", sequence(ncol(A_df))-1, sep = "_")

#convert column F into wide format by splitting it into multiple columns
F_df <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(as.character(df$F),'\\s+')), stringsAsFactors = F)
colnames(F_df) <- paste("F", sequence(ncol(F_df))-1, sep = "_")

#final data
final_df <- cbind(df[, !names(df) %in% c("A", "F")], A_df, F_df)
```

which gives

```
final_df    
#  Start.Date End.Date Subject Start.Time End.Time     B         C        D     E       Q        T       U
#1   05/20/18 05/20/18       1   16:23:11 17:26:24 7.000 12000.000 9500.000 1.000 203.000 1200.100 218.000
#      W       X     Y     Z   A_0   A_1   A_2   A_3       F_0      F_1       F_2      F_3       F_4
#1 7.000 347.000 0.000 0.000 1.000 0.000 0.000 0.000 11500.000 9500.000 13500.000 7500.000 15500.000
#       F_5       F_6
#1 5500.000 17500.000
```

Answer (score 1):

The good news is that your file does NOT have different delimiters. It is "Debian Control File" format. The whitespace marks continuous lines. See `?read.dcf` Unfortunately, I cannot figure out if there is a way to parse .dcf including the semantics of continuous lines. But what the heck, once the data is in R, you can just clean it with `library(tidyr)`

```
x <- read.dcf("yoursourcefilename.txt")
y <– as.data.frame(x) # read.dcf reads in as matrix

z <- y %>% 
       separate("A", into = c("drop", "A0"), sep = "0:") %>% 
       separate("A0", into = c("drop", paste0("A0_val_", 1:4)), sep = "\\s{2,}") %>% 
       separate("F", into = c("drop", "F0"), sep = "0:") %>% 
       separate("F0", into = c("F0", "F5"), sep = "5:") %>% 
       separate("F0", into = c("drop", paste0("F0_val_", 1:5)), sep = "\\s{2,}") %>% 
       separate("F5", into = c("drop", paste0("F5_val_", 1:2)), sep = "\\s{2,}") %>%
       select(-drop) %>% t() %>% as.data.frame()

z$V1 <- trimws(z$V1) # clean whatever whitespace is left
```

This will yield you a long dataframe:

```
 dim(z)
[1] 27  1
```

Like so:

```
  > z
                  V1
Start Date  05/20/18
End Date    05/20/18
Subject            1
Start Time  16:23:11
End Time    17:26:24
B              7.000
C          12000.000
D           9500.000
E              1.000
Q            203.000
T           1200.100
U            218.000
W              7.000
X            347.000
Y              0.000
Z              0.000
F5_val_1    5500.000
F5_val_2   17500.000
F0_val_1   11500.000
F0_val_2    9500.000
F0_val_3   13500.000
F0_val_4    7500.000
F0_val_5   15500.000
A0_val_1       1.000
A0_val_2       0.000
A0_val_3       0.000
A0_val_4       0.000
```

I am not sure this is the most efficient  to work with the data (not a tidy format), but sounds like this is what you wanted?